# Lazy evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation

C++ does not have native support for lazy evaluation (as Haskell does).

I'm wondering if it is possible to implement lazy evaluation in C++ in a reasonable manner. If yes, how would you do it?

EDIT: I like Konrad Rudolph's answer.

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement it in a more generic fashion, for example by using a parametrized class lazy that essentially works for T the way matrix_add works for matrix.

Any operation on T would return lazy instead. The only problem is to store the arguments and operation code inside lazy itself. Can anyone see how to improve this?

Comment: Below examples are specific to working on matrices.
When you are trying to set this up generically, this thread might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868129/how-to-store-variadic-template-arguments

Answer (score 119, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it is possible to implement lazy evaluation in C++ in a reasonable manner. If yes, how would you do it?

Yes, this is possible and quite often done, e.g. for matrix calculations. The main mechanism to facilitate this is operator overloading. Consider the case of matrix addition. The signature of the function would usually look something like this:

```
matrix operator +(matrix const& a, matrix const& b);
```

Now, to make this function lazy, it's enough to return a proxy instead of the actual result:

```
struct matrix_add;

matrix_add operator +(matrix const& a, matrix const& b) {
    return matrix_add(a, b);
}
```

Now all that needs to be done is to write this proxy:

```
struct matrix_add {
    matrix_add(matrix const& a, matrix const& b) : a(a), b(b) { }

    operator matrix() const {
        matrix result;
        // Do the addition.
        return result;
    }
private:
    matrix const& a, b;
};
```

The magic lies in the method `operator matrix()` which is an implicit conversion operator from `matrix_add` to plain `matrix`. This way, you can chain multiple operations (by providing appropriate overloads of course). The evaluation takes place only when the final result is assigned to a `matrix` instance.

**EDIT** I should have been more explicit. As it is, the code makes no sense because although evaluation happens lazily, it still happens in the same expression. In particular, another addition will evaluate this code unless the `matrix_add` structure is changed to allow chained addition. C++0x greatly facilitates this by allowing variadic templates (i.e. template lists of variable length).

However, one very simple case where this code would actually have a real, direct benefit is the following:

```
int value = (A + B)(2, 3);
```

Here, it is assumed that `A` and `B` are two-dimensional matrices and that dereferencing is done in Fortran notation, i.e. the above calculates *one* element out of a matrix sum. It's of course wasteful to add the whole matrices. `matrix_add` to the rescue:

```
struct matrix_add {
    // … yadda, yadda, yadda …

    int operator ()(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
        // Calculate *just one* element:
        return a(x, y) + b(x, y);
    }
};
```

Other examples abound. I've just remembered that I have implemented something related not long ago. Basically, I had to implement a string class that should adhere to a fixed, pre-defined interface. However, my particular string class dealt with huge strings that weren't actually stored in memory. Usually, the user would just access small substrings from the original string using a function `infix`. I overloaded this function for my string type to return a proxy that held a reference to my string, along with the desired start and end position. Only when this substring was actually used did it query a C API to retrieve this portion of the string.

Comment: This is the style of answer I was looking for. I especially like the trick with the cast operator overloading.

Comment: Actually, I'm not fully satisfied with the above solution. Because if you do "matrix_add D = A + (B + C)", I imagine B + C is evaluated right there. Maybe the way to go is to have the + operator accept matrix_add's as parameters.

Comment: I think the above is a bare bones example. It is easily extensable to your suggestion of A + B + C;

Comment: The other problem with this is that it will reevaluate the lazy operation each time the value is requested, rather than just the first time.

Comment: @Chris: yes, this is another problem. It too can be solved (e.g. by caching a value once calculated) but this only makes my example more complicated. ;-)

Comment: @Chris - Thats actually the point of lazy evaluation. So you can change a value in one of them, and it will be reevaluated each time. If you don't want this, then just do it concretely once.

Comment: @Steve: no, it isn’t. Haskell uses lazy evaluation everywhere but that doesn’t mean that everything is re-evaluated every time the value is needed. Rather, some functions *expect* that re-evaluation doesn’t happen if not necessary. For example, check out the “canonical” implementation of the Fibonacci sequence: `1 : 1 : [ a+b | (a,b) <- zip fib (tail fib) ]` – using this definition to execute `take 50 fib` clearly shows that re-evaluation does not happen, otherwise runtime would be exponential instead of linear (as observed).

Comment: Good example, but one thing need to be noted here: if any operand is changed/assigned, the lazy add should also be evculated.

Answer (score 39):

Boost.Lambda is very nice, but [Boost.Proto](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/proto/doc/html/index.html) is *exactly* what you are looking for.  It already has overloads of *all* C++ operators, which by default perform their usual function when `proto::eval()` is called, but can be changed.

Comment: +1, Any reference to a Boost library that gets half the work done for you in a portable and safe way is good to have.

Answer (score 33):

What Konrad already explained can be put further to support nested invocations of operators, all executed lazily. In Konrad's example, he has an expression object that can store exactly two arguments, for exactly two operands of one operation. The problem is that it will only execute *one* subexpression lazily, which nicely explains the concept in lazy evaluation put in simple terms, but doesn't improve performance substantially. The other example shows also well how one can apply `operator()` to add only some elements using that expression object. But to evaluate arbitrary complex expressions, we need some mechanism that can *store* the structure of that too. We can't get around templates to do that. And the name for that is `expression templates`. The idea is that one templated expression object can store the structure of some arbitrary sub-expression recursively, like a tree, where the operations are the nodes, and the operands are the child-nodes. For a *very* good explanation i just found today (some days after i wrote the below code) see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090421155750/http://ubiety.uwaterloo.ca/~tveldhui/papers/Expression-Templates/exprtmpl.html).

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
struct AddOp {
    Lhs const& lhs;
    Rhs const& rhs;

    AddOp(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs):lhs(lhs), rhs(rhs) {
        // empty body
    }

    Lhs const& get_lhs() const { return lhs; }
    Rhs const& get_rhs() const { return rhs; }
};
```

That will store any addition operation, even nested one, as can be seen by the following definition of an operator+ for a simple point type:

```
struct Point { int x, y; };

// add expression template with point at the right
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs> AddOp<AddOp<Lhs, Rhs>, Point> 
operator+(AddOp<Lhs, Rhs> const& lhs, Point const& p) {
    return AddOp<AddOp<Lhs, Rhs>, Point>(lhs, p);
} 

// add expression template with point at the left
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs> AddOp< Point, AddOp<Lhs, Rhs> > 
operator+(Point const& p, AddOp<Lhs, Rhs> const& rhs) {
    return AddOp< Point, AddOp<Lhs, Rhs> >(p, rhs);
}

// add two points, yield a expression template    
AddOp< Point, Point > 
operator+(Point const& lhs, Point const& rhs) {
    return AddOp<Point, Point>(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Now, if you have

```
Point p1 = { 1, 2 }, p2 = { 3, 4 }, p3 = { 5, 6 };
p1 + (p2 + p3); // returns AddOp< Point, AddOp<Point, Point> >
```

You now just need to overload operator= and add a suitable constructor for the Point type and accept AddOp. Change its definition to:

```
struct Point { 
    int x, y; 

    Point(int x = 0, int y = 0):x(x), y(y) { }

    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    Point(AddOp<Lhs, Rhs> const& op) {
        x = op.get_x();
        y = op.get_y();
    }

    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    Point& operator=(AddOp<Lhs, Rhs> const& op) {
        x = op.get_x();
        y = op.get_y();
        return *this;
    }

    int get_x() const { return x; }
    int get_y() const { return y; }
};
```

And add the appropriate get_x and get_y into AddOp as member functions:

```
int get_x() const {
    return lhs.get_x() + rhs.get_x();
}

int get_y() const {
    return lhs.get_y() + rhs.get_y();
}
```

Note how we haven't created any temporaries of type Point. It could have been a big matrix with many fields. But at the time the result is needed, we calculate it *lazily*.

Comment: Nice! However, when you want to lazily store p1 + (p2 + p3), how do yo specify its type :D?

Comment: yeah, that's actually a pity in current C++. you you would have to write out the type, or have to use polymorphism to store it without writing it out. Next C++ has auto, so you can do auto p = a + b; but that would have other problems: the temporaries created by "a + b" (the expression templates)...

Comment: would be destroyed after the full expression, and then we would be left with dangling references. so it gets hairy quite easily :)

Comment: you can parameterize the expression templates on whether they use references or not. then you can create a "lazy expression type" lazy_expr e = a + (b + c); when assigned to that one, the expression template would be deep copied. i.e all references to sub-expressions would be copied.

Comment: except the references to plain Point objects, which would still be held by reference. that way it could work. storing the expression into lazy_expr requires it to have a templated constructor, and creating a polymorphic type wrapping the expression internally. When actually evaluating it, ...

Comment: you would need one virtual function call to get the machinery started.

Comment: In C++11 distinguishing between temporaries and no temporaried could be nicdly done via a template specialization for rvalue references, thus allowing expressions like : Point p1; point p2; auto exp=p1+p2; exp2=exp*exp + point(1);

Comment: As the Point class get complex, you need to add all possible `+` by hand. To make it simpler you could make the two arguments of `+` be templates as well.

Answer (score 13):

I have nothing to add to Konrad's post, but you can look at [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for an example of lazy evaluation done right, in a real world app. It is pretty awe inspiring.

Answer (score 4):

I'm thinking about implementing a template class, that uses `std::function`. The class should, more or less, look like this:

```
template <typename Value>
class Lazy
{
public:
    Lazy(std::function<Value()> function) : _function(function), _evaluated(false) {}

    Value &operator*()  { Evaluate(); return  _value; }
    Value *operator->() { Evaluate(); return &_value; }

private:
    void Evaluate()
    {
        if (!_evaluated)
        {
            _value = _function();
            _evaluated = true;
        }
    }

    std::function<Value()> _function;
    Value _value;
    bool _evaluated;
};
```

For example usage:

```
class Noisy
{
public:
    Noisy(int i = 0) : _i(i)
    {
        std::cout << "Noisy(" << _i << ")"  << std::endl;
    }
    Noisy(const Noisy &that) : _i(that._i)
    {
        std::cout << "Noisy(const Noisy &)" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Noisy()
    {
        std::cout << "~Noisy(" << _i << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    void MakeNoise()
    {
        std::cout << "MakeNoise(" << _i << ")" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int _i;
};  

int main()
{
    Lazy<Noisy> n = [] () { return Noisy(10); };

    std::cout << "about to make noise" << std::endl;

    n->MakeNoise();
    (*n).MakeNoise();
    auto &nn = *n;
    nn.MakeNoise();
}
```

Above code should produce the following message on the console:

```
Noisy(0)
about to make noise
Noisy(10)
~Noisy(10)
MakeNoise(10)
MakeNoise(10)
MakeNoise(10)
~Noisy(10)
```

Note that the constructor printing `Noisy(10)` will not be called until the variable is accessed.

This class is far from perfect, though. The first thing would be the default constructor of `Value` will have to be called on member initialization (printing `Noisy(0)` in this case). We can use pointer for `_value` instead, but I'm not sure whether it would affect the performance.

Comment: In C++17 and newer, this could be implemented idiomatically using [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Answer (score 4):

Johannes' answer works.But when it comes to more parentheses ,it doesn't work as wish. Here is an example.

```
Point p1 = { 1, 2 }, p2 = { 3, 4 }, p3 = { 5, 6 }, p4 = { 7, 8 };
(p1 + p2) + (p3+p4)// it works ,but not lazy enough
```

Because the three overloaded + operator didn't cover the case

```
AddOp<Llhs,Lrhs>+AddOp<Rlhs,Rrhs>
```

So the compiler has to convert either (p1+p2) or(p3+p4) to Point ,that's not lazy enough.And when compiler decides which to convert ,it complains. Because none is better than the other .
Here comes my extension: add yet another overloaded operator +

```
    template <typename LLhs, typename LRhs, typename RLhs, typename RRhs>
AddOp<AddOp<LLhs, LRhs>, AddOp<RLhs, RRhs>> operator+(const AddOp<LLhs, LRhs> & leftOperandconst, const AddOp<RLhs, RRhs> & rightOperand)
{
    return  AddOp<AddOp<LLhs, LRhs>, AddOp<RLhs, RRhs>>(leftOperandconst, rightOperand);

}
```

Now ,the compiler can handle the case above correctly ,and no implicit conversion ,volia!

Comment: Have anyone thought about how to extend this method to handle operator- operator* operator/, even further you can add more unary ops such as log()/exp()/sin()/... and each of these op would require a new type, how many possible lhs/rhs type-combinations would be?

Answer (score 2):

As it's going to be done in [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions), by lambda expressions.

Comment: I'll give you a point if you tell me what possible values x has :D

Comment: Theres also a joke about c++0x being a hex value

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible.

It depends on exactly what you mean:

```
class X
{
     public: static X& getObjectA()
     {
          static X instanceA;

          return instanceA;
     }
};
```

Here we have the affect of a global variable that is lazily evaluated at the point of first use.

As newly requested in the question.
And stealing Konrad Rudolph design and extending it.

The Lazy object:

```
template<typename O,typename T1,typename T2>
struct Lazy
{
    Lazy(T1 const& l,T2 const& r)
        :lhs(l),rhs(r) {}

    typedef typename O::Result  Result;
    operator Result() const
    {
        O   op;
        return op(lhs,rhs);
    }
    private:
        T1 const&   lhs;
        T2 const&   rhs;
};
```

How to use it:

```
namespace M
{
    class Matrix
    {
    };
    struct MatrixAdd
    {
        typedef Matrix  Result;
        Result operator()(Matrix const& lhs,Matrix const& rhs) const
        {
            Result  r;
            return r;
        }
    };
    struct MatrixSub
    {
        typedef Matrix  Result;
        Result operator()(Matrix const& lhs,Matrix const& rhs) const
        {
            Result  r;
            return r;
        }
    };
    template<typename T1,typename T2>
    Lazy<MatrixAdd,T1,T2> operator+(T1 const& lhs,T2 const& rhs)
    {
        return Lazy<MatrixAdd,T1,T2>(lhs,rhs);
    }
    template<typename T1,typename T2>
    Lazy<MatrixSub,T1,T2> operator-(T1 const& lhs,T2 const& rhs)
    {
        return Lazy<MatrixSub,T1,T2>(lhs,rhs);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the technique I've used. (although I wouldn't say "anything" is possible. ;)

Comment: another nice "lazy creation" is to create a large vector of boost::optional<T> . they demonstrate it on their website

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 lazy evaluation similar to hiapay's answer can be achieved using std::shared_future. You still have to encapsulate calculations in lambdas but memoization is taken care of:

```
std::shared_future<int> a = std::async(std::launch::deferred, [](){ return 1+1; });
```

Here's a full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

#define LAZY(EXPR, ...) std::async(std::launch::deferred, [__VA_ARGS__](){ std::cout << "evaluating "#EXPR << std::endl; return EXPR; })

int main() {
    std::shared_future<int> f1 = LAZY(8);
    std::shared_future<int> f2 = LAZY(2);
    std::shared_future<int> f3 = LAZY(f1.get() * f2.get(), f1, f2);

    std::cout << "f3 = " << f3.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f2 = " << f2.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f1 = " << f1.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is not correct because calling `get()` multiple times on the same future is an undefied behaviour. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) ("The behavior is undefined if valid() is false before the call to this function." and "valid() is false after a call to this method.")

Answer (score 1):

C++0x is nice and all.... but for those of us living in the present you have Boost lambda library and Boost Phoenix. Both with the intent of bringing large amounts of functional programming to C++.

Comment: This answer, as written, without more details, has no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take Haskell as our inspiration - it being lazy to the core.
Also, let's keep in mind how Linq in C# uses Enumerators in a monadic (urgh - here is the word - sorry) way.
Last not least, lets keep in mind, what coroutines are supposed to provide to programmers. Namely the decoupling of computational steps (e.g. producer consumer) from each other.
And lets try to think about how coroutines relate to lazy evaluation.

All of the above appears to be somehow related.

Next, lets try to extract our personal definition of what "lazy" comes down to.

One interpretation is: We want to state our computation in a composable way, *before* executing it. Some of those parts we use to compose our complete solution might very well draw upon huge (sometimes infinite) data sources, with our full computation also either producing a finite or infinite result.

Lets get concrete and into some code. We need an example for that! Here, I choose the fizzbuzz "problem" as an example, just for the reason that there is some nice, lazy solution to it.

In Haskell, it looks like this:

```
module FizzBuzz
( fb
)
where
fb n =
    fmap merge fizzBuzzAndNumbers
    where
        fizz = cycle ["","","fizz"]
        buzz = cycle ["","","","","buzz"]
        fizzBuzz = zipWith (++) fizz buzz
        fizzBuzzAndNumbers = zip [1..n] fizzBuzz
        merge (x,s) = if length s == 0 then show x else s
```

The Haskell function `cycle` creates an infinite list (lazy, of course!) from a finite list by simply repeating the values in the finite list forever. In an eager programming style, writing something like that would ring alarm bells (memory overflow, endless loops!). But not so in a lazy language. The trick is, that lazy lists are not computed right away. Maybe never. Normally only as much as subsequent code requires it.

The third line in the `where` block above creates another lazy!! list, by means of combining the infinite lists `fizz` and `buzz` by means of the single two elements recipe "concatenate a string element from either input list into a single string". Again, if this were to be immediately evaluated, we would have to wait for our computer to run out of resources.

In the 4th line, we create tuples of the members of a finite lazy list `[1..n]` with our infinite lazy list `fizzbuzz`. The result is still lazy.

Even in the main body of our `fb` function, there is no need to get eager. The whole function returns a list with the solution, which itself is -again- lazy. You could as well think of the result of `fb 50` as a computation which you can (partially) evaluate later. Or combine with other stuff, leading to an even larger (lazy) evaluation.

So, in order to get started with our C++ version of "fizzbuzz", we need to think of ways how to combine partial steps of our computation into larger bits of computations, each drawing data from previous steps as required.

You can see the full story in [a gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/ruffianeo/b95e7ebfaa1e5ce09c2e55943e6201c9).

Here the basic ideas behind the code:

Borrowing from C# and Linq, we "invent" a stateful, generic type `Enumerator`, which holds
  - The current value of the partial computation
  - The state of a partial computation (so we can produce subsequent values)
  - The worker function, which produces the next state, the next value and a bool which states if there is more data or if the enumeration has come to an end.

In order to be able to compose `Enumerator<T,S>` instance by means of the power of the `.` (dot), this class also contains functions, borrowed from Haskell type classes such as `Functor` and `Applicative`.

The worker function for enumerator is always of the form: `S -> std::tuple<bool,S,T` where `S` is the generic type variable representing the state and `T` is the generic type variable representing a value - the result of a computation step.

All this is already visible in the first lines of the `Enumerator` class definition.

```
template <class T, class S>
class Enumerator
{
public:
    typedef typename S State_t;
    typedef typename T Value_t;
    typedef std::function<
        std::tuple<bool, State_t, Value_t>
        (const State_t&
            )
    > Worker_t;

    Enumerator(Worker_t worker, State_t s0)
        : m_worker(worker)
        , m_state(s0)
        , m_value{}
    {
    }
    // ...
};
```

So, all we need to create a specific enumerator instance, we need to create a worker function, have the initial state and create an instance of `Enumerator` with those two arguments.

Here an example - function `range(first,last)` creates a finite range of values. This corresponds to a lazy list in the Haskell world.

```cpp
template <class T>
Enumerator<T, T> range(const T& first, const T& last)
{
    auto finiteRange =
        [first, last](const T& state)
    {
        T v = state;
        T s1 = (state < last) ? (state + 1) : state;
        bool active = state != s1;
        return std::make_tuple(active, s1, v);
    };
    return Enumerator<T,T>(finiteRange, first);
}
```

And we can make use of this function, for example like this: `auto r1 = range(size_t{1},10);` - We have created ourselves a lazy list with 10 elements!

Now, all is missing for our "wow" experience, is to see how we can compose enumerators.
Coming back to Haskells `cycle` function, which is kind of cool. How would it look in our C++ world? Here it is:

```cpp
template <class T, class S>
auto
cycle
( Enumerator<T, S> values
) -> Enumerator<T, S>
{
    auto eternally =
        [values](const S& state) -> std::tuple<bool, S, T>
    {
        auto[active, s1, v] = values.step(state);
        if (active)
        {
            return std::make_tuple(active, s1, v);
        }
        else
        {
            return std::make_tuple(true, values.state(), v);
        }
    };
    return Enumerator<T, S>(eternally, values.state());
}
```

It takes an enumerator as input and returns an enumerator. Local (lambda) function `eternally` simply resets the input enumeration to its start value whenever it runs out of values and voilà - we have an infinite, ever repeating version of the list we gave as an argument:: `auto foo = cycle(range(size_t{1},3));` And we can already shamelessly compose our lazy "computations".

`zip` is a good example, showing that we can also create a new enumerator from two input enumerators. The resulting enumerator yields as many values as the smaller of either of the input enumerators (tuples with 2 element, one for each input enumerator). I have implemented `zip` inside `class Enumerator` itself. Here is how it looks like:

```cpp
// member function of class Enumerator<S,T> 
template <class T1, class S1>
auto
zip
( Enumerator<T1, S1> other
) -> Enumerator<std::tuple<T, T1>, std::tuple<S, S1> >
{
    auto worker0 = this->m_worker;
    auto worker1 = other.worker();
    auto combine =
        [worker0,worker1](std::tuple<S, S1> state) ->
        std::tuple<bool, std::tuple<S, S1>, std::tuple<T, T1> >
    {
        auto[s0, s1] = state;
        auto[active0, newS0, v0] = worker0(s0);
        auto[active1, newS1, v1] = worker1(s1);
        return std::make_tuple
            ( active0 && active1
            , std::make_tuple(newS0, newS1)
            , std::make_tuple(v0, v1)
            );
    };
    return Enumerator<std::tuple<T, T1>, std::tuple<S, S1> >
        ( combine
        , std::make_tuple(m_state, other.state())
        );
}
```

Please note, how the "combining" also ends up in combining the state of both sources and the values of both sources.

As this post is already TL;DR; for many, here the...

**Summary**

Yes, lazy evaluation can be implemented in C++. Here, I did it by borrowing the function names from haskell and the paradigm from C# enumerators and Linq. There might be similarities to pythons itertools, btw. I think they followed a similar approach.

My implementation (see the gist link above) is just a prototype - not production code, btw. So no warranties whatsoever from my side. It serves well as demo code to get the general idea across, though.

And what would this answer be without the final C++ version of fizzbuz, eh? Here it is:

```cpp
std::string fizzbuzz(size_t n)
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> SVec;
    // merge (x,s) = if length s == 0 then show x else s
    auto merge =
        [](const std::tuple<size_t, std::string> & value)
        -> std::string
    {
        auto[x, s] = value;
        if (s.length() > 0) return s; 
        else return std::to_string(x);
    };

    SVec fizzes{ "","","fizz" };
    SVec buzzes{ "","","","","buzz" };

    return
    range(size_t{ 1 }, n)
    .zip
        ( cycle(iterRange(fizzes.cbegin(), fizzes.cend()))
          .zipWith
            ( std::function(concatStrings)
            , cycle(iterRange(buzzes.cbegin(), buzzes.cend()))
            )
        )
    .map<std::string>(merge)
    .statefulFold<std::ostringstream&>
    (
        [](std::ostringstream& oss, const std::string& s) 
        {
            if (0 == oss.tellp())
            {
                oss << s;
            }
            else
            {
                oss << "," << s;
            }
        }
        , std::ostringstream()
    )
    .str();
}
```

And... to drive the point home even further - here a variation of fizzbuzz which returns an "infinite list" to the caller:

```cpp
typedef std::vector<std::string> SVec;
static const SVec fizzes{ "","","fizz" };
static const SVec buzzes{ "","","","","buzz" };

auto fizzbuzzInfinite() -> decltype(auto)
{
    // merge (x,s) = if length s == 0 then show x else s
    auto merge =
        [](const std::tuple<size_t, std::string> & value)
        -> std::string
    {
        auto[x, s] = value;
        if (s.length() > 0) return s;
        else return std::to_string(x);
    };

    auto result =
        range(size_t{ 1 })
        .zip
        (cycle(iterRange(fizzes.cbegin(), fizzes.cend()))
            .zipWith
            (std::function(concatStrings)
                , cycle(iterRange(buzzes.cbegin(), buzzes.cend()))
            )
        )
        .map<std::string>(merge)
        ;
    return result;
}
```

It is worth showing, since you can learn from it how to dodge the question what the exact return type of that function is (as it depends on the implementation of the function alone, namely how the code combines the enumerators).

Also it demonstrates that we had to move the vectors `fizzes` and `buzzes` outside the scope of the function so they are still around when eventually on the outside, the lazy mechanism produces values. If we had not done that, the `iterRange(..)` code would have stored iterators to the vectors which are long gone.

Answer (score 0):

Using a very simple definition of lazy evaluation, which is the value is not evaluated until needed, I would say that one could implement this through the use of a pointer and macros (for syntax sugar).

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

#define lazy(var_type) lazy_ ## var_type

#define def_lazy_type( var_type ) \
    typedef _Atomic var_type _atomic_ ## var_type; \
    typedef _atomic_ ## var_type * lazy(var_type);  //pointer to atomic type

#define def_lazy_variable(var_type, var_name ) \
    _atomic_ ## var_type _ ## var_name; \
    lazy_ ## var_type var_name = & _ ## var_name;

#define assign_lazy( var_name, val ) atomic_store( & _ ## var_name, val )
#define eval_lazy(var_name) atomic_load( &(*var_name) )

#include <stdio.h>

def_lazy_type(int)

void print_power2 ( lazy(int) i )
{
      printf( "%d\n", eval_lazy(i) * eval_lazy(i) );
}

typedef struct {
    int a;
} simple;

def_lazy_type(simple)

void print_simple ( lazy(simple) s )
{
    simple temp = eval_lazy(s);
    printf("%d\n", temp.a );
}


#define def_lazy_array1( var_type, nElements, var_name ) \
    _atomic_ ## var_type  _ ## var_name [ nElements ]; \
    lazy(var_type) var_name = _ ## var_name; 

int main ( )
{
    //declarations
    def_lazy_variable( int, X )
    def_lazy_variable( simple, Y)
    def_lazy_array1(int,10,Z)
    simple new_simple;

    //first the lazy int
    assign_lazy(X,111);
    print_power2(X);

    //second the lazy struct
    new_simple.a = 555;
    assign_lazy(Y,new_simple);
    print_simple ( Y );

    //third the array of lazy ints
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        assign_lazy( Z[i], i );
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int r = eval_lazy( &Z[i] ); //must pass with &
        printf("%d\n", r );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You'll notice in the function `print_power2` there is a macro called `eval_lazy` which does nothing more than dereference a pointer to get the value just prior to when it's actually needed.  The lazy type is accessed atomically, so it's completely thread-safe.