# Operator overloading as friend function error

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I'm trying to use + to add 2 vector (mathematical vector). Here's my code:

```
class Vector{
    double v[Max_size];
    int dim;
public:
    int getDim() const;
    Vector();
    Vector(int n);
    Vector(const Vector& a);
    Vector add(const Vector&b);
    friend Vector operator+(Vector summand1, Vector summand2);
};
```

Operator overloading:

```
Vector operator+(Vector summand1, Vector summand2){
    int dim1 = summand1.getDim();
    int dim2 = summand2.getDim();
    assert(dim1 == dim2);
    Vector sum(dim1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
        sum.v[i] = summand1.v[i] + summand2.v[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And how I use it:

```
Vector m = v+t;
```

When I run the code, it always shows that m is (0,0) (2D vector), which is the default value generated by the constructor. What's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: Your problem isn't in the code posted, can you post more details that will enable us run the code?

Comment: I'd definitely want to see the copy constructor.

Comment: BTW... for efficiency reasons, I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/414260/1621391

Comment: full code: http://codepad.org/8iNmAhYz

Comment: @T.C. I think it would use the default copy constructor. My code posted above has another way to add 2 vector, and it seems to work properly without manually creating the copy constructor.

Comment: On a side note, had you used `std::vector` instead of a C-style array, you wouldn't have needed the copy constructor for the code to work properly.

Comment: @pzelasko I'd love to, but this is an assignment :)

Comment: To avoid this question being closed, you must post your problem in the form of an [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& a){
    dim = a.dim;
    Vector(dim);
}
```

correctly sets the value of the `dim` member, but has not other side effect.

You should have a variant of the following code:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& a) : dim(a.dim) {
    std::copy(std::begin(a.v), std::end(a.v), v);
}
```

This will actually copy the data present in the parameter, and you will see the correct behavior for the code:

```
// Copy constructor called here, but did not correctly copy the data before.
Vector m = v + t;
```

---

For a better (by that I intend simpler and safer) Vector class, if you have access to a compiler that is at least C++11 compliant, you can write:

```
class Vector{
    std::array<double, Max_size> v; // Note the std::array here.
    int dim;
public:
    int getDim() const;
    Vector();
    Vector(int n);
    Vector(const Vector& a);
    Vector add(const Vector&b);
    friend Vector operator+(Vector summand1, Vector summand2);
};
```

The `std::array` will take care of everything, provided you write your copy constructor like this:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& a) : v(a.v), dim(a.dim) {

}
```

Or, even better, you could then let the compiler generate the copy constructor itself, with the same behavior.

Comment: bingo! but what is the meaning of : dim(a.dim) ?

Comment: dim(a.dim) constructs the dim member with the value a.dim. In C++, it is preferred, more optimized and sometimes mandatory to initialize class members like that. Search "member initialization list" for more info on this syntax.