# Convention for leaving body of an if/else blank

Tags: if-statement, coding-style

**Disclaimer**

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right SE for this, but I'll start here anyway.

**Background**

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402807/how-to-make-a-variable-always-equal-to-the-result-of-some-calculations) earlier and was looking at this code snippet in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55402932/7330924)

```
auto z = [&](){ static auto cache_x = x; 
    static auto cache_y = y; 
    static auto cache_result = x + y;
    if (x == cache_x && y == cache_y)
       return cache_result;
    else
    {
        cache_x = x; 
        cache_y = y; 
        cache_result = x + y;
        return cache_result;
    }
};
```

Personally, I would be inclined to rewrite it as follows, with a single return statement

```
auto z = [&](){ static auto cache_x = x; 
    static auto cache_y = y; 
    static auto cache_result = x + y;
    if (x == cache_x && y == cache_y)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        cache_x = x; 
        cache_y = y; 
        cache_result = x + y;
    }
    return cache_result;
};
```

but this leaves a blank body for the `if` part.

We could rewrite the `if/else` to just be `if(!(x == cache_x && y == cache_y))` but this runs the risk of being misunderstood (and can get messy).

**My Question**

What is the more accepted way of writing something like this, should we

- have multiple return statements
- leave the body of the `if` blank
- rewrite the `if` condition to be the negated version
- something else

---

Please note, I usually code in Java whereas the sample code is in C++. I am interested in the generally accepted way of doing things, as opposed to specific C++ constructs/methods.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll post it over there too

Comment: This is very opinion-based. To make it cleaner, it would be best to declare a boolean on the previous line and then use a negation of that within the if-statement.

Comment: @HassnainAli Ooh, that's a neat way of doing it, can't believe I didn't think of that one!

Comment: @mdfst13 hence me saying **if** it is a working code

Answer (score 1):

> I would be inclined to rewrite it […] with a single return statement

That's my preference also. You can get there more clearly by reversing the condition for the branch:

```c
auto z = [&](){
    static auto cache_x = x; 
    static auto cache_y = y; 
    static auto cache_result = x + y;
    if (!(x == cache_x && y == cache_y)) {
        cache_x = x; 
        cache_y = y; 
        cache_result = x + y;
    }
    return cache_result;
};
```

In general, if there's a branching logic (in this case, the `if ... else ...`) with one branch empty, try to rewrite it without that empty branch at all.